# Android Studio: Retrieving corresponding value from SQLite Database after selecting item from spinner

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm new to Android Studio and currently working on my first application.

I have a spinner that has been populated with data from an SQLite database. The database has 3 columns, namely "ID","Ingredient_Name" (text) and "Carbohydrate_Content" (double) - the spinner shows all data from the Ingredient_Name column.

Now, if the user selects an item from the spinner, I want to retrieve/fetch the corresponding data of that selected item. For example, if the user selects "Rice" from the spinner, I want to get the value of the Carbohydrate_Content of Rice. This (double) value will then be used for another mathematical equation.

I found the following code from android hive which is similar to what i want to do however, in the website this function is never called in the main activity.
My main question is how do i call it and apply it in my case? Thanks!

```
public Contact getContact(int id) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
            KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_ID + "=?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(id) }, null, null, null, null);

    if (cursor != null)
        cursor.moveToFirst();

    Contact contact = new Contact(Integer.parseInt(cursor.getString(0)),
            cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2));

    return contact;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that as opposed to copying and pasting the code, you deconstruct it and understand it first. I'll help you a bit here. So after the user has selected something in the spinner, wire up a button to do the DB call.

For that you can use an `onClickListener`. Get a reference to your button using `findViewById` then set the onClickListener. In the `onClickListener`, do the DB call, I would do:

`Cursor cursor = db.query(TABLE_CONTACTS, new String[] { KEY_ID,
    KEY_NAME, KEY_PH_NO }, KEY_NAME + " = ?",
    new String[] { String.valueOf(spinner.getSelectedItem()) }, null, null, null);`

So you're using the word "Rice" to search the DB because the spinner will return the word "Rice" so you want to match that. Then update your views accordingly. Let me know if you have any more questions in the comments.